# Indicate rows coalesce has updated

Tags: r, dplyr

In a new column, I would like to indicate  each time coalesce updates a missing record.

*Purpose*: I have a dataset with missing categorical codes. To replace the missing values, I use multiple `left_join/coalesce` operations that replace NAs with correct codes. I would like to keep track of which values were changed during each iteration.

```
# DATA
df <- tibble(
x =  c(1, 2,  3, NA, NA), #<Original data
y = c( 1, NA, 3, 4, NA)   #<New data from join
)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2    NA
3     3     3
4    NA     4
5    NA    NA
```

I would like to see...

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x changed  
  <dbl> <chr>    
1     1 no.change
2     2 no.change
3     3 no.change
4     4 corrected
5    NA no.change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = coalesce(x, y)) %>% 
  mutate(changed = case_when(
    x == new | is.na(new) ~ "no.change",
    TRUE ~ "corrected")) %>% 
  select(new, changed) # %>% rename(x = new)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    new changed  
#  <dbl> <chr>    
#1     1 no.change
#2     2 no.change
#3     3 no.change
#4     4 corrected
#5    NA no.change
```